# Using a bash script in AWS CICD Code Pipeline

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, deployment, build, cicd

In my company we have to use AWS native for the CICD process. I'm used to deploying my services via a bash script which makes deployments very flexible. However, I can't seem to find an option in AWS CodePipeline in which I can call on a script. In the build phase I am able to call on a buildspec.yml file, but in the deploy phase I would like to be able to call on a bash script. Does anyone know if that's possible using AWS CodePipeline?

Comment: You can run CodeBuild second time.

Comment: Where are you deploying the code? EC2 instances?

Comment: Looks like that can only run a YAML file: Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: did not find expected <document start> at line 4

Comment: I'm trying to deploy a glue job

Comment: I now have it working with referencing my bash script in the yaml

Answer (score 0):

This is what I put in the deployspec.yml to make it call on a bash script:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  shell: bash
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.8
    commands:
    - source deployspec.sh && create-stack-name && upload-to-s3 && create-cf-stack
```